# Display a signed float in UILabel

Tags: ios, floating-point, uilabel, sign

I know there's a "hard" way to do that (not that hard, but not straight up).

I display a float value as a percentage in a label that way :

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", myFloat];
```

I want to force the label to display the sign of the float. Of course, it automatically shows the "-" if the value is negative. I know I can do that using a method of that type :

```
-(NSString *) stringFromFloat: (float) theFloat {

    if (theFloat > 0) return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"+%.1f%%", theFloat];
    else return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.1f%%", theFloat];
}
```

But that would imply calling `[self stringFromFloat:aFloat];` every time I need to display the float value. I know using this solution is "better" because it lowers the number of re-used lines, but if my labels don't all show the same number of decimals, the `stringFromFloat:` may grow fast...

So my question is : is there an "easy" and standard way of doing this ? Like an NSString formatter or something ? For example, replacing `@"%.1f%%"` with something like `@"%sign%.1f%%"` ?

If there's nothing that straight, is something like `stringFromFloat:` the best solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to make the sign part of the format - it can be parameterized, like this:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.1f%%", myFloat<0 ? @"" : @"+", myFloat];
```

Even if you want to put it in the format, the format string can be prepared in an expression:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:myFloat<0 ? @"%.1f%%" : @"+%.1f%%", myFloat];
```

Comment: Well, it works great ! I used the first one and it's perfect. Just for general knowledge, how is this "action" called (the part with the *switch-like* comparison) ? It looks like it behaves like blocks but I don't know how to name it ? Thanks a lot for the quick answer !

Comment: @rdurand This is the [conditional or ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C), it is the same in Objective C and in C/C++/Java/C#. It's called "ternary" because it takes three operands - a condition, an "if true" expression, and an "if false" expression.